# Next-Auth getServerSession not retrieving user data in Nextjs 13.4 API Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I need to access user session data in a Next-Auth/Nextjs 13.4 API Route. I have configured the JWT and Session callback; however, the user data I specified in the callback function does not translate to what getServerSession is pulling in an API route. However, the session data does correctly reflect in a Client page when using useSession() so I'm not sure what the issue is.

**[...nextauth]/route.js**

```
import { connectToDB } from "@/app/server/db";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

// Authorize function
async function authorize(credentials) {
    const { email, password } = credentials;
    const { db } = await connectToDB("Tenants");
    const user = await db.collection("Users").findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isPasswordValid) { return null; }
        await db.collection("Users").updateOne({ email }, { $set: { lastLoggedIn: new Date() } });
        return user
    }
    return null;
}

export const authOptions = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            authorize
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            return { ...token, ...user };
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user = token;
            return session;
        }
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    },
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    NEXTAUTH_URL: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL
});

export { authOptions as GET, authOptions as POST };
```

**User Object**

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "615fb61796e77940b7f7a5e7"
  },
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "password": "$2b$12$fCADz/THWfE7.hThRiFj2eNJxTL78.7zPtyRtERxkBlU2hwlYRJ9K",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "lastLoggedIn": {
    "$date": "2023-07-21T17:36:06.893Z"
  },
  "phoneNumber": "",
  "role": "Admin",
  "status": "Active",
  "company": "TestCompany",
  "jobTitle": "TestJobTitle",
  "department": "TestDepartment"
}
```

**API Route**

```
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"

export async function GET(request) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    console.log(session)
}
```

**Client Page - Console Log Output**

```
user {
  "_id": "615fb61796e77940b7f7a5e7",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "password": "$2b$12$fCADz/THWfE7.hThRiFj2eNJxTL78.7zPtyRtERxkBlU2hwlYRJ9K",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "lastLoggedIn": "2023-07-21T17:36:06.893Z",
  "phoneNumber": "",
  "role": "Admin",
  "status": "Active",
  "company": "TestCompany",
  "jobTitle": "TestJobTitle",
  "department": "TestDepartment"
  "iat": 1689960966,
  "exp": 1692552966,
  "jti": "ae91e614-4fdb-4de4-9e5e-5b9879ca07ba"
}
```

**API Route - Console Log Output**

```
{
  user: { name: undefined, email: 'test@test.com', image: undefined }
}
```

**Expected Output**

The expected output of the user session data should match the user object.

```
{    
  user: {
      "_id": "615fb61796e77940b7f7a5e7",
      "email": "test@test.com",
      "password": "$2b$12$fCADz/THWfE7.hThRiFj2eNJxTL78.7zPtyRtERxkBlU2hwlYRJ9K",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "lastLoggedIn": "2023-07-21T17:36:06.893Z",
      "phoneNumber": "",
      "role": "Admin",
      "status": "Active",
      "company": "TestCompany",
      "jobTitle": "TestJobTitle",
      "department": "TestDepartment"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this. In your `auth/[...nextauth].js` file include some callbacks with session and jwt like so:

```
export default NextAuth({
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, user, token }){
            // Assign the userid and role from the jwt callback below
            if(session?.user) { session.user.id = token.uid; session.user.role=token.roleid }
            return session
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }){
            if(user) { token.uid = user.id; token.roleid=user.role  }
            return token;
        },
    },
    session:{ strategy:'jwt' },
    providers:[
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials, request){
                // await dbconnect()
                // Login to authenticate the user from Database or other data sources

                return({ id: 'userid1', name: 'Patsy Khan', role: '64e3abe6322c1065da3awee4'})
            }
        })
    ]
})
```

I'm just returning hardcoded data: id, name and role. Accessing it from the client-side is like this:

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

.....
const{data:session, status}=useSession()// from next-auth


{session && status==='authenticated' ? <SomeComponent /> }

<button type="button" onClick=()=>{ handler(session?.user.id) } > {session?.user.name} </button>
```

From the server side however we need to set `authOptions` in the `auth/[...nextauth].js` file. I already included the callbacks above. So simply copy the callbacks from above and include it in an `export const authOptions` and add it to the ...nextauth file:

```
export const authOptions={
    callbacks:{
        async session({ session, user, token }){
            // Assign the userid and role from the jwt callback below
            if(session?.user) { session.user.id = token.uid; session.user.role=token.roleid }
            return session
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }){
            if(user) { token.uid = user.id; token.roleid=user.role  }
            return token;
        },
    },
}
```

Now we could access all the data in the server side like so:

```
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next'
import { authOptions } from '../[...nextauth]'

export default async function handler(request, response) {

    const session=await getServerSession(request, response, authOptions)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(session, null, 2))
```

Output:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "Patsy Khan",
        "id": "userid1",
        "role": "64e3abe6322c1065da3awee4"
    },
    "expires": "2023-12-12T02:58:59.567Z"
}
```

`"next-auth": "^4.24.5", "next": "13.5.4",`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply export the authOptions object from [...nextauth]/route.ts like:

```js
export const authOptions = {
   //...
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to v5 (which is currently expiremental) fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but searching on the web I found what solved my problem. So, to get the full User object in server side, you need to call getServerSession() in a server component and make sure to pass your authOptions as it's argument, like this: `getServerSession(authOptions)`.

PS: credits for "@balazsorban44" in this link: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7658